# Include links for certain paragraphs

Tags: cross-referencing, paragraphs, links

I would like to include links/reference points in my latex document, e.g.

[image: Picture showing 3 pages and a link from page 3 to page 1]

The situation is the following:

There is a certain paragraph on, say page 11, and on page 13 there is a link and when the reader clicks this link (which does not necessarily have to be blue) then the reader is taken to the desired paragraph on page 11.

And I imagined my code to look like this:

```
Lie groups are smooth manifolds
...
Lie algebra.

\CreateLink{LabelLie}{Paragraph about Lie groups}
Lie groups play an enormous role in modern geometry, 
  ...
and are studied in representation theory.

In the 1940s–1950s, Ellis Kolchin, Armand Borel
  ...
in number theory.

On a "global" level, whenever a 
  ...
analysis on the manifold.  (see \LinkTo{LabelLie})
```

Is such a construction possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several methods in `hyperref`:

- `\hypertarget` and `\hyperlink` can be used to create an anchor and a link to that anchor.
- `\phantomsection\label{foo}` can be referenced with arbitrary text as `\hypererf[foo]{arbitrary text}`.
- The following example uses `\refstepcounter` that automatically sets an anchor.
  By redefining `\the<counter>` the text is setup for later use with `\ref`:

The example file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcounter{partextdummy}
\newcommand*{\CreateLink}[2]{%
  \begingroup
    \renewcommand*{\thepartextdummy}{#2}%
    \ifhmode
      % raise the anchor above the base line in horizontal mode
      \raisebox{2ex}[0pt][0pt]{%
        \refstepcounter{partextdummy}%
        \label{#1}%
      }%
    \else
      \refstepcounter{partextdummy}%
      \label{#1}%
    \fi
  \endgroup
  \ignorespaces
}
\newcommand*{\LinkTo}{\ref}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\CreateLink{nam}{Paragraph about nam dui ligula}
\lipsum[2]
\lipsum[3]
See \LinkTo{nam}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: May I just ask what the line
    \renewcommand*{\thepartextdummy}{#2}%
does ?

Comment: `\refstepcounter{<counter>}` advances the counter by one and `\label` will use `\the<counter>` for the referenced number that `\ref` refers to. `\renewcommand*{\the<counter>}{#2}` replaces that number with `#2`.

Comment: I am not a latex pro, but couldn't I run the risk of overwriting another command each time I use \CreateLink ?

Comment: `\CreateLink` is defined by `\newcommand` that complains, if the command already exists. The redefinition of `\thepartextdummy` is local (because of `\begingroup` and `\endgroup`) and the command belongs to the counter `partextdummy`.